# What is the time complexity of the following algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++ {
        Simple Statement
    }
}
for (int k = 0; i < n; k++ {
    Simple Statement
    Simple Statement
    Simple Statement
    Simple Statement
    Simple Statement
}
    Simple Statement*25
```

For the nested loop, I find a time complexity of 1 (for int i = 0) + n + 1 (for i < n) + n (for i++) * [ 1 (for int j = 0 ) + 1 + n ( for j < n) + n ( for j++) ] + n (for the simple statement). This is (1+n+1+n)*(1+1+n+n)+n = (2 + 2n)*(2+2n)+n = 4n^2 + 9n + 4.

For the following loop, I find a time complexity of 1 (for int k = 0) + n + 1 (for i < n) + n (for k++) + 5n (for the five simple statements). This is 1+n+1+n+5n = 7n+2. For the next 25 simple statements, I find they have a time complexity of 25.

So the total time complexity is 4n^2 + 8n + 4 + 5n + 2 + 25 = 4n^2 + 16n + 31, however, my book says the time complexity is n^2 + 5n + 25.

What have I done wrong?

Edit: It is now apparent that the book is telling the time complexity of *only* the simple statements. I suppose now my question is this (as it was in the title): What is the time complexity of the algorithm?

Comment: `n^2` for the nested loop, `5n` for the following loop, and `25` for the last line. Not necessarily time complexity, but counting the number of statements executed.

Comment: Worth noting is as n goes to infinity the time complexity is n^2 up until constant factors.  This is because the k loop and 25 statements become vanishingly small compared to top loop.  That's why we call this `O(n^2)`

Comment: You also have an error on the calculation of your nested loop. The product should actually be 1 + (n + 1) + n + n * (1 + (n + 1) + n + n) = 2n + 2 + n * (3n + 2) = **3n^2 + 4n + 2**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your book is counting *only* the number of `SimpleStatements` executed.

Comment: Am I correct if you look at the time complexity of the entire algorithm? I suppose now I can see how they found out the time complexity of the simple statements - n^2 for the nested loop, 5n for the next 5 statements inside a loop, and 25 for the statements outside of the loop yielding n^2+5n+25.

Comment: Your analysis is fine, too.  The book was probably just trying to keep things simple.  You are allowed to count what are called "elementary operations".  Perhaps "simple statements" take a little longer than the basic assignments and comparisons and increments, and are considered more important by the book's authors.

Comment: This is why big-O notation is what is typically actually used in the real world. This scales like n^2, and that's usually what you care about -- getting something like `n^2+5n+25` tends to require assumptions that don't really make sense in the real world.