# Instruction execution of a C++ code

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, asymptotic-complexity

Hello I have an algorthm in C++ and I want to find the instructions executed. The code is below

```
cin >> n;   
for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
     for (j = 1; j <= n; j ++) 
     A[i][j] = 0;

for(i=1;i<=n;i++) 
A[i][i] = 1;
```

now, after my calculation, I got this **T(n) = n^2+8n-5**. I just need someone else to verify if I am correct. Thanks

Comment: I get a different number. How did you get yours?

Comment: 1+2(n-1+1)+ n-1 + (n-1(n+1))/2 + n-2.
That was how I arrived at T(n) = n^2+8n-5

Comment: What instructions do you take in account?

Comment: Hello, what do you mean by instructions? This has to do with the time complexity. I don't quite understand what you mean.

Comment: You wrote "find the instructions executed". So I asked what instructions you want to count - for example, there are n^2+n array element assignments

Comment: Let me just put that I am interested in the time function T(n) ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let's do an analysis step by step.

The first instruction

```
cin >> n
```

counts as one operation: **1**.

Then the loop

```
for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
     for (j = 1; j <= n; j ++) 
     A[i][j] = 0;
```

Let's go from inside out. The `j` loop performs n array assignments (`A[i][j] = 0`), (n + 1) `j <= n` comparisons and n `j ++` assignments. It also performs once the assignment `j = 1`. So in total this gives: n + (n +1) + n + 1 = 3n + 2.

Then the outer `i` loop performs (n + 1) `i <= n` comparisons, n `i ++` assignments and executes n times the `j` loop. It also performs one `i = 1` assignment. This results in: n + (n + 1) + n * (3n + 2) + 1 = **3n^2 + 4n + 2**.

Finally the last for loop performs n array assignments, (n + 1) `i <= n` comparisons and n `i ++` assignments. It also performs one assignment `i = 1`. This results in: n + (n + 1) + n + 1 = **3n + 2**.

Now, adding up three operations we get:

(1) + (3n^2 + 4n + 2) + (3n + 2) = **3n^2 + 7n + 5 = T(n)** total operations.

The time function is equivalent, assuming that assignments, comparisons, additions and `cin` are all done in constant time. That would yield an algorithm of complexity O(n^2).

This is of curse assuming that n >= 1.

Comment: Hi, What if I say 1 for(j=1) n+1 for(j<=n) and n for(j++) giving 2n+1 is that wrong? you got 3n+1. could you explain the different from what I just did?

Comment: @henryjoseph you're right, I miscalculated the number of comparisons. I edited and recalculated. The only error in your reasoning is that you also need to put into the count of operations the actual action done inside the loop, not only the checks on the bounds

Comment: so you mean I should have added an extra n+1 to the 2n+1? what would the extra n+1 be for? Please, could you re-edit your answer if you miscalculated something?

Comment: @henryjoseph I'm not sure what you mean by an extra (n+1). I did edit to correct my miscalculations, on the answer I explain every aspect I considered to get to the result, which part in particular is not clear? To the 2n + 1 you actually need to add the (1) of the `j=1` and the n array assignments :)

Comment: take alook at this link which I am following to do mine : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12851857/what-is-the-time-complexity-of-the-following-algorithm?rq=1
what could have been different because the fellow also used 2n+1 instead of 3n+2.

Comment: @henryjoseph I believe the guy that posted that question has some errors in his formulas, some wrong parenthization and reasoning that render his proof incorrect. In particular he's counting the `Simple statement` as if it were outside the inner loop, ergo he gets (2n + 2) instead of (3n + 2) when he does the product. And the product is also incorrectly formulated.

Comment: how about the statements : A[i][j] = 0;? I don't see them added in your calculation? I will try your analysis on another solution and see if it matched up.

Comment: @henryjoseph "The `j` loop performs n array assignments". That's the `A[i][j] = 0` statements. Edited the answer so it is clearer.

Comment: Thanks alot for your time. one final question.you said this: "and executes n times the j" and that means n*(3n+2) does that means that the j function(3n+2) is multiplied by the number of times the j runs which is n?

Comment: @henryjoseph Yes, it is just as if you were counting them one by one. Executing the full `j` loop costs (3n + 2) operations. And you are executing n full `j` loops, so the total number of operations is n * (3n + 2)